# How to click on a label tag within nested divs in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on an 'Select all' label on a website but I am having troubles.  The HTML has it the label nested within several divs.     [HTML Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gpfkr.png) here.

I have tried various XPATH examples but nothing actually clicks the element. Any ideas?

Here is my latest attempt:

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div//label[contains(., 'Select all')]")**strong text**

**UPDATE**

I was able to select the options individually with the following code:

```
select_element = driver.find_element(By.ID,'availableList')
select_object = Select(select_element)


all_available_options = select_object.options
count_of_options = len(all_available_options)
for x in range(count_of_options):
    select_object.select_by_index(x)
```

Comment: how many element does it identify with xpath //div//label[contains(., 'Select all')]

Comment: @SonaliDas - I have not counted the number of elements.  I should have been more specific with the other attempts that I tried.  For example,  there is an ID associated with the label I am trying to select so I first tried driver.find_element(By.ID,'availableAll').click().  The behavior is the same with the XPATH code.

Comment: @toyotaSupra - There is not actually any errors in this case.  The code I thought would work is driver.find_element(By.ID,'availableAll').click().   The div that contains the label shifts a little when the code is executed, but it is not selected and there is no error.  I will take your advice on posting the code next time.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It has unique ID you can use that instead of XPATH.

driver.find_element(By.ID,'availableAll').click()

or you can use full XPATH it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I tried that initially and it did not work.  I just tried again to make sure I didn't do something wrong the first time.  What is strange is that the entire div shifts position a bit when that code is executed.  I have tried several other options that affect the div in the same way but the 'Select all' is never selected.